How to drag vertically (in row) but increase vertically (in colum) in excel?
So, I have data in B10:B117 (in column B) that I want to put in row B140:DE140 (row 140). I know that I can just special paste transpose, But I want to write it like, =B10, =B11, =B12, so if the value change, I don't have to change it manually. I tried to put =B10 on B140 then drag it horizontally, instead of =B11, it jump to =C10, I also tried to lock the column, but it's not working, anyone know how to do it?

"I can just special paste transpose" - use button Paste Link instead OK

In the new Excel, the easiest way is to do this:
=TRANSPOSE(B10:B117)

The result is then in the form of a dynamic array.
In addition, you can also use formulas that return single results. These need to be copied:
=INDIRECT("B"&COLUMN()+8)
=INDEX($B$10:$B$117,COLUMN()-1)


If you are using MS365 can make use of TOROW() function as well:
=TOROW(B10:B117,1)


One can read the MSFT Documentations here.
